# После перезаписи файлов вебсайта ASP .NET MVC IIS загружает страницы очень медленно

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis

После перезаписи файлов вебсайта ASP .NET MVC IIS загружает страницы очень медленно.

Приходиться прощалкивать каждую позицию в меню чтобы каждая страница открылась.
После этого работает быстро.

Какие параметры настройки сайта на это влияют?

Как решить этот вопроос?

Душевно благодарю.

Comment: Precompiled views.

Comment: @Igor Отлично! А возможно представить ваш ответ в  развернутом виде с детальными инструкциями?

Comment: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1169354/Pre-compiled-Razor-View-in-ASP-NET-MVC